# Update UserID and PhoneNumber in PUSH_DEVICES table

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Using MFP 8, Related to PUSH NOTIFICATION and USERLOGIN Security check, If i register a device, I can see in MFP CONSOLE (DEVICE SECTION) and PUSH_DEVICES Table as well.

In PUSH_DEVICES table (UserId is anonymous) and phonenumber is empty.

How to update these 2 from app (NOT BY REST SERVICE) ?

if the userid is anonymous, i cannot see the USERID and DISPLAY NAME in DEVICES Section of MFP CONSOLE as well

Answer (score 0):

Push device registration and subscription takes an independent path. These steps have to be done separately.
However, the user identity assigned against Push device registration and subscription flows from identity created using the securitycheck that maps to "push.mobileclient".

If you see "anonymous" user against your push registration, this normally happens when you make the push registration when an identity has not already been established with the secuirtycheck. 
Verify your application code flow and ensure you do `MFPPush.registerDevice()` only after authentication is complete. You can use network traffic analysis to understand your current sequence.

Comment: Let me put down the steps i have done..
1. Added the scope "push.mobileclient" with UserLogin Security Check
2. Calling userLoginChallengeHandler on App Initialize
3. On HandleSuccess, Calling check For PushSupported
4. On PushSupported Success, Calling Register Device
5. On Register Device, obtainAccessToken for "push.mobileclient" scope

From these, App authentication done properly, can see the Display name and Username in LOGS and DEVICES section

Still PUSH_DEVICE table shows anonymous instead of UserID

whats wrong in the flow ?

Comment: @Vinay, are you trying the push notifications sample? If not, can you try this sample:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/it/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/cordova/
Also ,can you provide your project.

Comment: I tried with Push Notification sample, its working fine but the same is not working when i Integrate with my app.. is that the flow correct whatever i said in previous comment ?

Comment: In general, yes. But lot will depend on what exactly is done in Step 2. And what sequence you execute in Step 5. Can you capture a network traffic analysis and see the sequence of steps? You can also share a sample project that recreates the issue.